# How to open sapi train window in a c# application?

Tags: c#, sapi

I want to open windows sapi train window in my application.

I find this process's file path is "C:\Windows\System32\Speech\SpeechUX\SpeechUXWiz.exe".But when i attempt to open it by dobule click,it faild.I try to open this file in my application by process.start() method will be faild too.

```
 Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\Speech\SpeechUX\SpeechUXWiz.exe");
```

Is there someone know how to open it? Is there a interface to do that in sapi? Thank you!

My system is windows7 x64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't start the process directly; the details of the command line are version-dependent (and, in fact, the process itself may change from version to version).

You can start training (in C#) using speechlib (the SAPI IDispatch-compatible API). Look at [ISpeechRecognizer::DisplayUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To use SpeechLib, add

```
using SpeechLib;
```

to your code, and add a reference (via Project/Add Reference/COM) to the `Microsoft Speech Object Library` to your project.

Then, to start training, you would have some code that looks like this:

```
static void RunTraining()
{
    SpSharedRecoContext RC = new SpSharedRecoContext();
    string Title = "My App's Training";
    ISpeechRecognizer spRecog = RC.Recognizer;
    spRecog.DisplayUI(hWnd, Title, SpeechLib.SpeechStringConstants.SpeechUserTraining, "");
}
```

Comment: Is there same method in System.Speech Namespace?Thank you.

Comment: I can't find "SpeechLib.SpeechUserTraining".Please provide more detailed examples for me ,thank you.

Comment: Try `SpeechLib.SpeechStringConstants.SpeechUserTraining`.  Bing is your friend.

Comment: how can I do it from a UWP app project that use Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition ?

Comment: @ClaudioCayoCastagnetti You don't; Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition doesn't support training (because it doesn't need it).