# how to add a custom lexicon in my c # project

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I m developing an c# project based on voice recognition. I want to recognize words in Indian English accent so for that i thought for lexicon & then adding pronunciations in that file but I m not getting how to add a lexicon in my project & how to create a lexicon?

Comment: It is entirely dependant on what speech recognition library you are using

Comment: i m using system.speech

Answer (score 1):

[Lexicons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee450829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) aren't exposed via System.Speech.Recognition, unfortunately.  You can access lexicons using the [SpeechLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) automation interface to SAPI, though; the object you want to create is [SpLexicon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note that System.Speech.Recognition will automatically load any user lexicons, so you can have a separate app to build the lexicon and your reco app can continue to use System.Speech.Recognition.

Also, if you're using a command & control grammar, you should specify pronunciations directly; for example, the [SrgsToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.srgsgrammar.srgstoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class allows you to explicitly specify a pronunciation for the word.  (Unfortunately, I can't remember how to do this with `System.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder`, but it is possible.)

Comment: thank you bro..can you give me some basic example of separate app for building lexicon?

Comment: @prafullagrawal Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994663/how-to-open-sapi-train-window-in-a-c-sharp-application/20028368#20028368) to see how to integrate SpeechLib, and then just call `new SpLexicon` to create the object and then call `AddPronunciation` to add the pronunciation.   Since you will likely need custom pronunciations, the [English phone set documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee431828(v=vs.85).aspx) will also be handy.