# Add words to DictationGrammar in C# Speech Recognition?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, grammar, system.speech.recognition

This is something that has bugged me for a while. I'm developing a C# application that uses voice control, and I was wondering if there is any possible way to load a DictationGrammar and then add words to it to improve accuracy. For instance: I'm trying to use it to search google and bing. It barely recognizes the word 'google' and has never recognized the word 'bing'. Is there any way to do this? DictationGrammar is not very accurate at all (it keeps adding words). Currently, I'm loading the grammar like this:

```
 PACSREC.LoadGrammarAsync(new DictationGrammar());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add words to the [user lexicon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125054(v=vs.85).aspx), and the DictationGrammar will implicitly add those words.

Unfortunately, the Lexicon APIs aren't exposed via the System.Speech.Recognition APIs; instead, you'll have to use the SpeechLib (automation-compatible) APIs to do so.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313934/how-to-add-a-custom-lexicon-in-my-c-project) for examples.