# How to add new word to speech dictionary on windows 7 using C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, sapi

I need to add thousands of new words to speech dictionary on windows 7 by visual studio from an input file to use in windows' native speech recognition. is it possible? Should I use Microsoft Speech API (SAPI) 5.4 ? If so help me with that. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with the System.Speech.Recognition library; you have to use the [speechlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994663/how-to-open-sapi-train-window-in-a-c-sharp-application/20028368#20028368) automation interface.

Once you've got a reference to speechlib in your project, you can add pronunciations using the [`AddPronunciation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method like this:

```
static void AddPronunciations()
{
    SpLexicon lex = new SpeechLib.SpLexicon();
    long langid = Thread.CurrentCulture.LCID;
    lex.AddPronunciation("word", langid);
}
```