# Class Not Registered Microsoft Speech Object library SpeechLib

Tags: c#

I have set a reference to speechlib and trying to run the following code:

```
static void RunTraining()
{
    SpSharedRecoContext RC = new SpSharedRecoContext();
    string Title = "My App's Training";
    ISpeechRecognizer spRecog = RC.Recognizer;
    spRecog.DisplayUI(hWnd, Title, 
    SpeechLib.SpeechStringConstants.SpeechUserTraining, "");
}
```

However I am getting a class not registered 0x80040154

As it is a com object library I am compiling x86 and I have also run regsvr32 on the sapi.dll but to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated, the code is in C#

Comment: Always use the [SpeechRecognizer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer?view=netframework-4.7.2) in a C# app, the friendly .NET wrapper for SAPI.  If it bombs as well then you know that the machine needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the speechrecognizer does not contain the interfaces that I need to access.

Comment: Well, that was not the point, the point was to verify that SAPI is properly installed.  You can't just arbitrarily use another library that has happy interfaces.  SAPI is a system component that can't be replaced, only an OS update qualifies.  The error message basically says that is what you have to do.  It would take a lot less guessing if you'd have mentioned your Windows version and the interface name.

Comment: Thanks Hans. It is the Microsoft speech object library (Speechlib/ COM). The code was posted by Eric Brown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994663/how-to-open-sapi-train-window-in-a-c-sharp-application/20028368#20028368

Comment: Windows 10 Professional

Comment: I tried on a different target installation and the same result and I have other applications running using the .net library successfully

Comment: Turns out that the displayUI calls the 64-bit DLL SpeechUX.DLL so if you compile as x64 it works. Thanks again.